# Getting external application minimize and maximize status. Cannot figure out error

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to get the status of my application when is maximized or minimized. I rewrote the script so that its specific for Excel application. However, I am getting an error on this line:

```
 Private Sub GetWindowStats(Process.GetProcessesByName("Excel")(0).MainWindowHandle)
```

It says that it needs a comma or ")" is expected. I can't see why it would need one and even if I put one, still get a compile error. Here is my entire code:

```
'Handle the minimize and maximize events on Excel.

Private Const SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED As Integer = 3
Private Const SW_SHOWMINIMIZED As Integer = 2
Private Const SW_SHOWNORMAL As Integer = 1

Private Structure POINTAPI
    Public x As Integer
    Public y As Integer
End Structure

Private Structure RECT
    Public Left As Integer
    Public Top As Integer
    Public Right As Integer
    Public Bottom As Integer
End Structure

Private Structure WINDOWPLACEMENT
    Public Length As Integer
    Public flags As Integer
    Public showCmd As Integer
    Public ptMinPosition As POINTAPI
    Public ptMaxPosition As POINTAPI
    Public rcNormalPosition As RECT
End Structure

Private Declare Function GetWindowPlacement Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As IntPtr, ByRef lpwndpl As WINDOWPLACEMENT) As Integer
Private Declare Function GetForegroundWindow Lib "user32" Alias "GetForegroundWindow" () As IntPtr

Private Sub GetWindowStats(Process.GetProcessesByName("Excel")(0).MainWindowHandle)
    Dim wp As WINDOWPLACEMENT
    wp.Length = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf(wp)
    GetWindowPlacement(Handle, wp)
    If wp.showCmd = SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED Then ' is window maximized?
        If Handle = GetForegroundWindow Then ' is the window foreground?
            MessageBox.Show("Maximized and forground")
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Maximized")
        End If
    ElseIf wp.showCmd = SW_SHOWNORMAL Then
        If Handle = GetForegroundWindow Then
            MessageBox.Show("Normal size and forground")
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Normal")
        End If
    ElseIf wp.showCmd = SW_SHOWMINIMIZED Then
        MessageBox.Show("Window is Minimized")
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because it need the type for the parameter for this sub routine not the value.

```
Private Sub GetWindowStats(Handle As IntPtr)
 Dim wp As WINDOWPLACEMENT
 wp.Length = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf(wp)
 GetWindowPlacement(Handle, wp)
 If wp.showCmd = SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED Then ' is window maximized?
    If Handle = GetForegroundWindow Then ' is the window foreground?
        MessageBox.Show("Maximized and forground")
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Maximized")
    End If
 ElseIf wp.showCmd = SW_SHOWNORMAL Then
    If Handle = GetForegroundWindow Then
        MessageBox.Show("Normal size and forground")
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Normal")
    End If
 ElseIf wp.showCmd = SW_SHOWMINIMIZED Then
    MessageBox.Show("Window is Minimized")
 End If
End Sub
```

To Call it:

```
GetWindowStats(Process.GetProcessesByName("Excel")(0).MainWindowHandle)
```

Remember if there are no Excel processes this will throw an error.

Comment: Hi Don, If I can't call it the way I had before, how can I then call GetProcessByName?

Comment: Did you try "EXCEL" that is how I see it.

Comment: what I meant is where do I put the line GetWindowStats(Process.GetProcessesByName("Excel")(0).MainWindowHandle) within my code.

Comment: That is how you call the method and pass it the first element of the processes that equals "Excel". Where you put it is up to you - when do you need to call that method?

Comment: Thanks, I would like to call it when Form1 loads